# Arcobjects vb.net stringbuilder

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net

I'm newbie and have question about string builder to show the arcgis layers.
(System: ArcGis 10.2, VisualStudio2012)
I don't succeed to show the loaded layers in a line of the message box.

code:

```vb
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI
Imports System.Text

Public Class LayerLoop2_Button1
  Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button

  Public Sub New()    
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnClick()
        AccessLayerViaMxDocument(My.ArcMap.Document)
        My.ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = Nothing
  End Sub

    Shared Sub AccessLayerViaMxDocument(ByVal pMxDocument As IMxDocument)
        Dim pMap As IMap
        Dim pMaps As IMaps = pMxDocument.Maps
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To pMaps.Count - 1 Step i + 1
            pMap = pMaps.Item(i)
            Debug.WriteLine(pMap.Name)
            MsgBox(pMap.Name)

            Dim pEnumLayer As IEnumLayer = pMap.Layers(Nothing, True)
            pEnumLayer.Reset()
            Dim pLayer As ILayer = pEnumLayer.Next()
            Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()

            While Not pLayer Is Nothing

                Debug.WriteLine(pLayer.Name)
                ' Show MessageBox with the name of the layer
                pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next()

                sb.Append(pLayer.Name)
                MsgBox(sb.ToString())
            End While
        Next
    End Sub
```

---

Can you explain me please what you mean with console output? As output I should just have a message box. In the code above I tried already to use the string builder - but without success....
The first given code was this:

```vb
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI

Public Class AccessLayer

Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnClick()

AccessLayerViaMxDocument(My.ArcMap.Document)
My.ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = Nothing
End Sub

Shared Sub AccessLayerViaMxDocument(ByVal pMxDocument As IMxDocument)

Dim pMap As IMap
Dim pMaps As IMaps = pMxDocument.Maps

Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To pMaps.Count - 1 Step i + 1
pMap = pMaps.Item(i)

Debug.WriteLine(pMap.Name)

MsgBox(pMap.Name)

Dim pEnumLayer As IEnumLayer = pMap.Layers(Nothing, True)
pEnumLayer.Reset()

Dim pLayer As ILayer = pEnumLayer.Next()
While Not pLayer Is Nothing
Debug.WriteLine(pLayer.Name)

MsgBox(pLayer.Name)

pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next()
End While

Next    
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnUpdate()
Enabled = My.ArcMap.Application IsNot Nothing    
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please **edit** the question to show the console output.  There isn't much in the way of GIS content, as it seems to be a VB issue.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your attention!  Can you explain me please what you mean with console output? As output I should just have a message box.

Comment: You've got "Debug.WriteLine" directives -- what are they doing?

Comment: If you're running it through the VS debugger, you should be able to add breakpoints in your code and stop it to check your values.  **If you don't know how to do that** I would advise going a little internet searching or posting another question.

Comment: Thank you for answering that quick! The debug.writeline should be for the name of Map and layer. I know how to set breakpoints but honestly I'm not able to use the information from there. And as I'm not on visual studio now, I can't tell you any message of failure...